# Bootstrap 3 Full screen Collapsible Navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullscreen, navbar

I'm trying to get Bootstrap 3's collapsable nav to open full screen and  centre it horizontally and vertically with a black background (taking up the full height and width of the screen) positioned behind the navigation links. I've managed to horizontally align the content using margin:auto but i'm unable to vertically align it. I've tried using display:table and vertically-align:middle, but to no avail.

Js fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/graphixwizardMattzpp/4VSmp/

The Html as follows...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-header">

<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
<i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
</button>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Fashion</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Beauty</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Advertising</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Portraiture</a></li>      
<li><a href="#">Motion</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

and the CSS -

```
.nav.navbar-nav {
float: none;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.navbar-nav {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.navbar-nav {
float: none!important;
font-size: 49px;
line-height: 43px;  
letter-spacing: 3px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
float: none;
}

.navbar-inverse {
background-color: transparent;
border-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
border-color: transparent; 
}

.navbar-toggle {
display: block;
float: none;
top: 52px;
left: 125px;
color: #FFF;
}

.nav>li{
display:block;
overflow: visible;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
color: #FFF;
background-color: transparent;
}

.collapsing {
opacity: 0;
transition:opacity 0.3s linear; 
 -webkit-transition:opacity 0.3s linear; 
 -moz-transition:opacity 0.3s linear; 
 -o-transition:opacity 0.3s linear;

}

.navbar-collapse.collapse.in{
opacity:0;
transition:opacity 0.3s linear; 
 -webkit-transition:opacity 0.3s linear; 
 -moz-transition:opacity 0.3s linear; 
 -o-transition:opacity 0.3s linear;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse{
opacity: 1;
transition:opacity 0.3s linear; 
 -webkit-transition:opacity 0.3s linear; 
 -moz-transition:opacity 0.3s linear; 
 -o-transition:opacity 0.3s linear;
}

.navbar-collapse {
width: 100%;
border-top: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
margin-top: 65px;
height: auto !important;
font-family: "aktiv-grotesk-std";
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 54px;
font-size: 60px;
display: block !important;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Any ideas or approach ?

I thank you all in advance.